# Cannot use Arquillian Graphene with Arquillian Drone

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I'm using `Arquillian 1.1.6.Final` for testing the `JSF` by using the `Arquillian Drone 2.0.0.Alpha3`. It works great. But when I'm adding the feature further by using the `Arquillian Graphene 2.1.0.Alpha1`, there is an exception as

```xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.WebElementEnricher.enrich(WebElementEnricher.java:68)
at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.GrapheneEnricher.enrich(GrapheneEnricher.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
```

Even I revert the `Arquillian Graphene` to version `2.0.3.Final`, the exception still thrown. Here is my `pom.xml`

```xml
<properties>
    <my.arquillian.drone.version>2.0.0.Alpha3</my.arquillian.drone.version>
    <my.arquillian.version>1.1.6.Final</my.arquillian.version>
    <!--my.arquillian.graphene.version>2.1.0.Alpha1</my.arquillian.graphene.version-->
    <my.arquillian.graphene.version>2.0.3.Final</my.arquillian.graphene.version>
    <my.arquillian.recorder.version>1.0.0.Beta1</my.arquillian.recorder.version>
    <my.arquillian.selenium.version>2.44.0</my.arquillian.selenium.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${my.arquillian.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${my.arquillian.selenium.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                  <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
                  <version>${my.arquillian.drone.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${my.arquillian.graphene.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <scope>${my.project.dependency.test.scope}</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My unit test is

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DroneTest {

    @Drone
    private WebDriver browser;

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void ensureIndexPage() {
        try{
            browser.get("http://www.google.com")
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); //<---- Exception in thrown here
        }
    }

}
```

As mention above, the unit test works fine without `Arquillian Graphene`. Could you please help to advise further?

Comment: I've figured it. My `super pom` contain the `rhq-arquillian-suite-extension`. After remove that dependency, the `Graphene 2.1.0.Alpha1` works fine. I'm looking for the another `Arquillian TestSuite Extension` that may work with `Graphene`. I will update once I've achieved.

Comment: For more info on Arquillian Graphene: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking for another `Arquillian Suite Extension` rather than the `rhq-arquillian-suite-extension` which is able to works with `Arquillian 1.1.6.Final`,  `Arquillian Drone 2.0.0.Alpha3` and `Arquillian Graphene 2.1.0.Alpha1`. I've found the [ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension](https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension) it works great for all of them.

Anyhow there is some limitation which it is a known issue that it cannot work with `Arquillian Warp` as [issue-16](https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension/issues/16).

If we would like to achieve the `code coverage` without `Arquillian Warp`, the `Jacoco` may help as mentioned at [JBoss Developer Forum: How to generate Code Coverage reports from Drone tests](https://developer.jboss.org/message/835744#835744).